# Why is the "cursor" contraint in MediaTrackSettings for video not supported?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-capture

I cannot remove the cursor from a shared window stream. The specification over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/cursor says it is supported in Chrome since version 71.
[image]

But trying it out, does not work at all:

```
const feed = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
   video: {
    displaySurface: 'window',
    cursor: 'never', // doesn't work
  },
  audio: false,
});
```

The compatibility info cannot be correct therefore, as querying the supported constraints does not list the cursor constraint option at all in Chrome.

[image]

So what gives? The MDN site says it is supported since version 71, but in reality it is not. What could be the reason here?